# Config Proprety in Extjs-6 Picker doese not work perfectly

Tags: extjs, picker, extjs6

I'm developing an application using [Extjs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/)-6. I extend a viewclass from a `Ext.form.field.Picker` as follow:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.MyCombo', function(){
    var me;

    var initComponent = function()
    {
        me = this;
        Ext.apply(me, {});
        me.callParent(arguments);
    };

    var createPicker = function ()
    {
        var textfield = {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            width: '100%',
            border: false,
            listeners: {
                change: function(component, newValue)
                {
                    me.setStr(newValue);
                }
            }
        };

        var panel = new Ext.panel.Panel({
            rtl: true,
            minWidth: 300,
            floating: true,
            items: [textfield]
        });

        Ext.Msg.alert('Attension', 'Init Value is : ' + me.getStr());
        return Ext.widget(panel);
    };

    return {
        extend: 'Ext.form.field.Picker',
        alias: 'widget.mycombo',

        initComponent: initComponent,
        createPicker: createPicker,
        config: {
            str: ''
        }
    };
});
```

I use this class as follow:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    title: 'Its me!',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'mycombo',
        name: 'item1'

    }, {
        xtype: 'mycombo',
        name: 'item2'
    }]
});
```

When I open first `mycombo`(item1) and type some word in textfield input, and then open second `mycombo` item(items2), in `createPicker` function I alert `str` value of item, and it show the item1's value.

**Why it show item1's str value?**

**Where is wrong?**

My Sample fiddle is [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/16bs).

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There are so many oddities in your code, where did you get those patterns from? I'd outline them but it's not really appropriate for an answer.

Comment: @aviram83 I want to implement an plugin like combobox & date

Comment: @EvanTrimboli You can this pattern at [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext-method-define)

Comment: Right, but that's nothing like the examples. The assignment of methods to vars, the weird `me = this` at the class level. Calling `Ext.widget` on an instance you just created.

Comment: this kinda fix your issue, [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/16cp)

Comment: @aviram83 It's not fixed

Comment: sorry, didn't save the right one, here is the fixed [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/16d2)